# How to use the data in the test resource folder during unit testing

Tags: java, junit

I have a folder in my intellij project which has some .svg files, with the path **"data/system/svgfiles1"**

I'm doing unit testing for a method that uses these .svg files.
When I run my test locally every test is Ok. 
But, in Jenkins I get an error.

The reason for this error is that I use some .svg files locally that the test needs and they are not in jenkins.

Now, the method defines a path where the data is placed. I commented where the path is defined. 
As you can see, the path is hard coded.

```
 public Optional<String> content(final Record content, final int sides) {
            final Optional<String> path = Utils.findAttachmentPathById(
                "./data/" + DataController.Sides[sides], // here I get the path "data/system/svgfiles1"
                content.getId()
        );
        if (!path.isPresent()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        Optional<String> value1 = Optional.empty();
        Optional<String> value2 = Optional.empty();
        try {
            value2 = Optional.of(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path.get()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            logger.error("An exception", ioException);
        }
        try {
            value1 = Optional.of(Record.format(value2.get(), content.getData()));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("An exception", exception);
        }
        return value1;
    }
```

Now I created a resource folder in the tests where I added these .svg files. 
The test method is this:

```
   @Test
    public void exportZipPlateSvgContentTest() {
        // prepare
        Record record = new Record(recordValues); // record values are only some string values
        record.setId(1L);

        // expected
        Optional<String> expected = Optional.of(values) 

        // test
        Optional<String> result = platesService.content(record, 1); // this is the method under test 

        // run
        assertEquals(expected, result 
    }
```

As you can see in the test method. The path is not given as a parameter. The path is hard coded in the **content** method.

Since the path is hard coded in the method. Is it possible for the method to use a different path during testing?

Like, when I test it to say use the data from "test/resources/data/svgfiles1"?

I would really appreciate any input. Please let me know to clarify anything.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding paths, you should be considering something like `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Comment: @Compass thank you for the idea, I will change it

Answer (score 0):

If you copy your files also to `src/test/resources` it should work.

Another approach would be to use a configuration property to specify where the files can be found and use your `application.properties` and `application-test.properties` to put in different values for production and testing.